# EPPLUS Format provider

Tags: c#, excel, xlsx, epplus

I'm trying to use EPPLUS to create an excel document. Can I format the `DateTime` of C# to another format LANGUAGE and write it into excel but keeping any date format and example?
I actually can format by this way

> EEEE d  MMMM y => Sunday 13 March 2018

```
ExcelPackage excel = new ExcelPackage();
excel.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Reporte de Incidencias");
var page = excel.Workbook.Worksheets["Reporte de Incidencias"];
page.Cells["D3:D" + z].Style.Numberformat.Format = "dddd dd MMMM YYYY";
```

But I want to create a culture info like in `es-MX` or `it-IT`, keeping the date format because sometimes I need to sort this dates in excel.
Does anyone know how?

Comment: So what you are asking is to format date according to culture info, not by  "dddd dd MMMM YYYY"?

Answer (score 1):

Just replace to string format by the culture info you wish to implement.

```
System.Globalization.CultureInfo mx = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("es-MX");
page.Cells["D3:D" + z].Style.Numberformat.Format =mx.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern.ToString();
//or
page.Cells["D3:D" + z].Style.Numberformat.Format =mx.DateTimeFormat.LongDatePattern.ToString();
//or
page.Cells["D3:D" + z].Style.Numberformat.Format =mx.DateTimeFormat.SortableDateTimePattern.ToString();
```